# Why does $\rho_{\mathbf{Z}^t\otimes P}=\rho_R$ imply the isomorphsim of $\mathbf{Z}^t\otimes P\cong R$?

Tags: representation-theory, modules, tensor-products, dihedral-groups

so I have happened upon a thesis regarding the calculations of various $\mathbf{Z}D_6$ modules and their isomorphisms and came across a technique which is bothering me. Let me give an example. Let $A=\mathbf{Z}D_6$ where $D_6=<1,x,y\:|\:x^3=y^2=1, yx=x^2y>$ and let $\mathbf{Z}^t$ be the module where $x$ acts trivially and $y$ acts by -1. Further, let $R=\mathbf{Z}[\omega]=\mathbf{Z}[x]/(x^2+x+1)$, i.e. the Eisenstein integers, and let $P=(1-\omega)R$. I want to show $\mathbf{Z}^t\otimes P\cong R$. The argument is as follows:
Since $\rho_{\mathbf{Z}^t\otimes P}(g)=\rho_R(g) \forall g\in D_6$, it follows that $\mathbf{Z}^t\otimes P\cong R$.
I want to know why the equality of representations implies an isomorphism since we are working over the integers and not an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Is $\rho$ the trace? Because otherwise what you're saying seems to be a tautology to me. An isomorphism of representations of $D_{6}$ over a ring $S$ is the same as an isomorphism of $SD_{6}$ modules.

Comment: No I mean the representation. If this was over $\mathbf{C}$, say, then this would indeed be immediate since then the traces would be equal and ofc then we have an isomorphism. However, as someone rightly pointed out to me, we have an example where the representations are the regular rep, but the modules are non-isomorphic. specifically, we let $A=\mathbf{Z}[C_2]$ and then consider $A$ as the regular $\mathbf{Z}G$ module, and then $N=U\oplus V$ where $U$ and $V$ are copies of the integers where the generator acts trivially on $U$ and by $-1$ on $V$. $A\not\cong N$

Comment: I still don't really get what you mean. Could you explain why A and N are not isomorphic as $\mathbb{Z}G$ modules? The same map that gives you the isomorphism as representations is also a morphism in the category of $\mathbb{Z}G$-modules.

Comment: Well, N is the direct sum of two rank 1 modules, but A is not. How can we construct an isomorphism between these?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my answer to your previous question. You asked "suppose we have two $\mathbb{Z}G$ modules $M$ and $N$ such that their representations are isomorphic. Clearly this means they have equal characters. What I am wondering is whether this implies $M\cong N$." I thought you were asking whether equal characters implied isomorphic modules (which was also what the title of your question implied). If the representations are isomorphic (rather than just the characters being equal) then the modules are isomorphic.

Comment: @Jeremy Rickard Thank you for the clarrification. However, I am still at a loss as to why these are isomorphic. Is it simply trivial or is there something going on in the background that I am missing?

Comment: You don't say in the question how $D_6$ is acting on $R$ and $P$?